# Why doesn't the hard_limit_line in Grafana, postgre SQL doesn't show for the whole part of the graph? Instead only half way?

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

There is a set Hard_limit_power for each cluster and in this case it's 190kW but the line only shows for a certain period and not for the entire graph region. How can i extend this line? The written code for the Hard_limit_power line is as below and it's written in an additional query:

```
SELECT 
  datalytics_inserted_at, 
  hard_limit_power*1000 as hard_limit_power 
from llm_cluster_updates 
where cluster_id = (Select cluster_id from charging_station_clusters where display_name = '$cluster_name') 
order by datalytics_inserted_at desc
```

[image]

I wanted the Hard_limit_power line to be shown in the entire graph section

Answer (score 0):

Try to include a constant value for the entire range of the graph. Assuming your graph's x-axis represents time and you want the line to extend from the earliest timestamp to the latest timestamp, you can use the MIN and MAX functions to retrieve the earliest and latest timestamps from the llm_cluster_updates table :

```
SELECT 
  datalytics_inserted_at, 
  hard_limit_power*1000 AS hard_limit_power 
FROM llm_cluster_updates 
WHERE cluster_id = (SELECT cluster_id FROM charging_station_clusters WHERE display_name = '$cluster_name') 
   OR datalytics_inserted_at = (SELECT MIN(datalytics_inserted_at) FROM llm_cluster_updates WHERE cluster_id = (SELECT cluster_id FROM charging_station_clusters WHERE display_name = '$cluster_name'))
   OR datalytics_inserted_at = (SELECT MAX(datalytics_inserted_at) FROM llm_cluster_updates WHERE cluster_id = (SELECT cluster_id FROM charging_station_clusters WHERE display_name = '$cluster_name'))
ORDER BY datalytics_inserted_at DESC
```

Comment: Generally speaking, joins are faster than subqueries, so I would prefer joins, where it is possible.